# What does the comma means in the following selling price formula?

Tags: notation

> (Direct Cost / (100, Desired Gross Profit)) * 100

Source: http://www.mrhvac.com/2011/10/26/how-to-calculate-the-selling-price-of-an-item/

I've never seen a comma placed like that in an equation. Why does it mean? Is it more commonly written in another way?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, if you looked just further down they have calculated in an example that $100, 65 =35$ or $100-65=35$. So, in this context the command actually stands for a minus sign giving us $$\text { Selling price } = \frac {\text {Direct cost}}{100-\text {Desired gross profit}} \times 100$$

*Personally*, I have never seen this symbol used as a substitute for the minus sign. Hope it helps.

Comment: Minus sign! Okay, no wonder I got confused.